# Add image toolbar button: Pop-up does not advise Ctrl+V is possible to paste from Clipboard

Tags: discussion

I was typing a new question today, and I needed to add an image.  By complete luck, I tried Ctrl+V to paste from my clipboard, and it magically worked.  I looked closer at the popup: There is no advice this is possible.

Am I missing something, e.g., "web blind"?  Else, this may be a nice, small UX improvement.

Sample screenshot:
[image]